# c++ 2 ref classes should have acess to one same object of a other class

Tags: c++, windows, reference, system, command-line-interface

I have 2 classes let's say class a und b. And even a thrid class c.

class a and b should have acess to the functions of the same object of class c. I want to have a member like a reference. So the argument in the construktor of class a and b would be the object or something like that.

Because I'm new to the CLI syntax im kinda confused with the datatype reference class.

---

so a normal example wihtout CLI and classes would like that.

```
        int c = 5; 
        int &a = c; 
        int &b  = c;
```

so whenever I change the value of a or b it changes the value of c.

I'm not a native english speaker so please be friendly :3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your class of `c` is a ref class, you can use `^` (handle) to reference it.

like the code here

```
 ref_class_c ^ d(gcnew ref_class_c);

 ref_class ^ e = d;
```

As for the tracking reference versus a handle, the difference is similar to a reference/out parameter in C# method versus the variable name.

For example, try the following code by yourself

```
 void test1(String^ s) {
     s = gcnew String("no change");
 }
 void test2(String^% s) {
     s = gcnew String("change");
 }
```

when you call these two functions, you will notice the difference.

```
 void test3(String^ s) {
     s = "new string 1";
 }
 void test4(String^% s) {
     s = "new string 2";
 }
```

In your case, either will work.

Comment: first thanks for editing I kinda failed that part aswell. So when I use the object e does it also do the changes to the object d because it's a reference?

Comment: yes, that is correct. Well, you can try it in your code.

Comment: But shouldn't I use the % symbol to make a reference? for example ref_class ^% e = d;

Comment: That is called a tracking reference. They both work.